# I am having a touble with float datatype in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem with `float` in C++:

```cpp
int main()
{
    float x = {1.1234567f};
    //cout << setprecision(7) << endl;
    cout << x;
}
```

The 5th decimal digit in `float x` doesn't print out:

> 1.12346

Comment: `ostream`'s default float formatting will output `precision` number of digits **total**, not `precision` number of digits **after the decimal** like you are expecting. `ostream`'s default `precision` is 6, which is exactly what you are seeing (6 digits printed, where the 5th digit after the decimal has been rounded up). Even in your commented-out example, a precision of 7 would cut off the `7` at the end and round up the `6`. You need to put the `ostream` into `fixed` mode to let the `precision` control the number of digits after the decimal, eg: `cout << fixed << setprecision(7) << endl;`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer, its because the digits are more than 7 and that's wrong. We all know so compiler doesn't print 5th, 6th decimal digit.

To solve this problem use:

```
cout<<setprecision(decimalDigitsNumberPlus1);
```

Comment: Now try printing a number `> 10`. The comment under the question provides a better solution.